# Copying multiple files in C

Tags: c, file, copy, cp

I have a problem when I try to copy multiple files in C.
It copies the first file in the directory, but no more.
Other files are not even open and I do not know how the problem is.
Any idea?

```
bool copyFileToDirectory(char *file, char *directory){
    int input_fd, output_fd;
    ssize_t ret_in, ret_out;
    char* buffer[2048];
    struct stat fileStat;

    /* Check permissions */
    access (directory, W_OK);
    if (errno == EACCES) {
        perror("Output file not writable");
        return false;
    }
    if (errno == EROFS) {
        perror("Output file not writable (read-only)");
        return false;
    }
    int rval = access (file, R_OK);
    if (rval != 0) {
        printf ("Input file is not readable (access denied)\n");
        return false;
    }

    /* Copy */
    input_fd = open (file, O_RDONLY);
    stat(file, &fileStat);

    chdir(directory);

    output_fd = open(file, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0666);
    chmod(file, fileStat.st_mode);

    while((ret_in = read (input_fd, &buffer, 2048)) > 0){
        ret_out = write (output_fd, &buffer, (ssize_t) ret_in);
        if(ret_out != ret_in){
            perror("An error has ocurred during the process\n");
            return false;
        }
    }

    close(input_fd);
    close(output_fd);

    return true;
```

}

Comment: You might consider switching *back* to the previous working directory after acquiring your second file descriptor.

Comment: Oh, I am a disaster. Of Course, thanks a lot.

Comment: No problem, and if you're about to ask: [`getcwd()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getcwd)

Comment: Yes, thanks. Problem solved. The post code has been edited.

Comment: @Seruk You can ( and is encouraged to ) answer your own question. It would be proper make an answer based on comments and your knowledge that solves your problem . Thank you.

Comment: You are doing a lot of error checking *before*, but you fail to check the return value *after* open() and stat() (BTW: fstat() will probably be more suited here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the problem, I added the following lines:

```
    char cwd[1024];
    getcwd(cwd, 1024);
```

*With this, I got the address of the current working directory.*

And later,

```
    chdir(cwd);
```

*We have to come back for subsequent copies*.

**Final code:**

```
bool copyToDirectory(char *file, char *directory){
    char cwd[1024];
    getcwd(cwd, 1024);
    int input_fd, output_fd;
    ssize_t ret_in, ret_out;
    char* buffer[2048];
    struct stat fileStat;

    /* Check permissions */
    access (directory, W_OK);
    if (errno == EACCES) {
        perror("Output file not writable");
        return false;
    }
    if (errno == EROFS) {
        perror("Output file not writable (read-only)");
        return false;
    }
    int rval = access (file, R_OK);
    if (rval != 0) {
        printf ("Input file is not readable (access denied)\n");
        return false;
    }

    /* Copy */
    input_fd = open (file, O_RDONLY);
    stat(file, &fileStat);

    chdir(directory);

    output_fd = open(file, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0666);
    chmod(file, fileStat.st_mode);

    while((ret_in = read (input_fd, &buffer, 2048)) > 0){
        ret_out = write (output_fd, &buffer, (ssize_t) ret_in);
        if(ret_out != ret_in){
            perror("An error has ocurred during the process\n");
            return false;
        }
    }

    close(input_fd);
    close(output_fd);

    chdir(cwd);

    return true; 
}
```